# Game Sprite Motion

Tags: physics, animation, spritekit, ui-design

I really like the effect that I see in [this video](https://youtu.be/utr6V8kVavE?t=2m40s) of Mario Party 10 Jewel Drop (at 2:40). It occurs when the four green orbs join together. You'll see a four items with long trails move to the top left of the screen quickly. What is the "science" behind the acceleration of these particles? Are there any resources that I can be directed to that discuss animation with UI? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This is based on the answer provided @Felsir.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    SKSpriteNode *ship = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    [ship setScale:0.2];
    [ship setPosition:CGPointMake(50, 300)];
    [self addChild:ship];

    CGPoint end = CGPointMake(500, 500);
    CGPoint ctrlB = CGPointMake(300, -100);
    CGPoint ctrlA = CGPointMake(400, 250);
    SKAction *fly = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:2 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime){
        node.position = [self bezierWithPointA:node.position B:ctrlA C:ctrlB D:end amount:elapsedTime];
        NSLog(@"position = (%f, %f)", node.position);
    }];
    [ship runAction:fly];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

}

-(CGPoint) bezierWithPointA:(CGPoint)pointA B:(CGPoint)pointB C:(CGPoint)pointC D:(CGPoint)pointD amount:(float)amount {
    CGPoint ab, bc, cd, abbc, bccd;
    ab = [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:pointA pointB:pointB amount:amount];
    bc = [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:pointB pointB:pointC amount:amount];
    cd = [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:pointC pointB:pointD amount:amount];
    abbc = [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:ab pointB:bc amount:amount];
    bccd = [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:bc pointB:cd amount:amount];
    return [self linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:abbc pointB:bccd     amount:amount];
}

-(CGPoint) linearInterpolationBetweenPointA:(CGPoint)pointA pointB:(CGPoint)pointB amount:(float)amount {
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(pointA.x + (pointB.x - pointA.x)*amount, pointA.y + (pointB.y - pointA.y)*amount);
    return newPoint;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trajectory of the particles is a Bézier curve. A Bézier curve is a smooth curve along four points:

pointA: startpoint
pointB: startdirection+acceleration
pointC: enddirection+accelleration
pointD: endpoint

Basically it generates a curve through from point A to point D, using the vectors towards A-B and C-D to determine the path.

See C# (Monogame) code example:

```
public static Vector2 bezier(Vector2 pointA, Vector2 pointB, Vector2 pointC, Vector2 pointD, float t)
{
    Vector2 ab, bc, cd, abbc, bccd;
    ab = Vector2.Lerp(pointA, pointB, t);
    bc = Vector2.Lerp(pointB, pointC, t);
    cd = Vector2.Lerp(pointC, pointD, t);
    abbc = Vector2.Lerp(ab, bc, t);
    bccd = Vector2.Lerp(bc, cd, t);
    return Vector2.Lerp(abbc, bccd, t);
}
```

The path is defined by the 4 points and float `t` from `0f`-`1.0f`. Note that due to the nature of the curve, the speedup and slowdown come with the curve.

For the effect, sparkles spawn along the path of the curve. The sparkles themselves could be regular particles that have their own behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have been more clear in my question. I'm using SpriteKit (objective C) for the Mac. I'm not sure how knowledgeable you are with that platform. I'll post the code I've created above. It's not behaving exactly as I expected, but it is creating that Bezier motion that you described in your answer.

Comment: The "time" variable seems to not be working correctly. I'm not sure how to limit it so that it's between 0f and 1.0f. I'm using a custom action block instead of the update method.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SpriteKit, but it seems you set an action of 2 seconds. The elapsedtime variable will be from 0 to 2? To keep it within bounds you'll need to divide the time by 2. In general to create a value between 0 and 1 (a percentage actually), percentage=currentvalue/totalvalue;

Comment: I think my control points were out of whack. I came across this website [link](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.19,.67,.79,1.54) and it really help me visualize where the control points needed to be. Normalizing the duration helped as well I think. Thanks so much!